# DRC Simulator can't run again, after installing Gazebo!

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Last week, DRC Sim still ran pretty smoothly after i [installed](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/InstallDRC) it in the pre - compiled binaries selection .

But then when i tried to install a [stand-alone version of Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/install#Pre-compiled_binaries), as suggested in the official DRC Kickoff Tutorials, to get familiar with it, it became a disaster!

Now, DRC Sim can't even run again, with a warning window poping up (sorry, i can't attach the screenshot here. It's required that i have at least 60 karma to do so)
. Frustrated, I've browsed through all ROS and Gazebo Q&As without any answer. Here's how the terminal diagnosed the problem:

```
process[tf2_buffer_server-6]: started with pid [4002]
[ WARN] [1352705611.085392264]: You've passed in true for auto_start for the C++ action server at [/tf2_buffer_server]. You should always pass in false to avoid race conditions.
Warning [parser.cc:375] Gazebo SDF has no <gazebo> element in file[/usr/share/drcsim-1.0/models/drc_robot/model.sdf]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[drc_robot_controllers_spawner-7]: started with pid [4031]
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1125] urdf2gazebo: link[left_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, parent joint [left_camera_optical_frame_joint] ignored
.Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1129] urdf2gazebo: link[left_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, not modeled in gazebo
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1125] urdf2gazebo: link[right_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, parent joint [right_camera_optical_frame_joint] ignored
.Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1129] urdf2gazebo: link[right_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, not modeled in gazebo
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camhand_controllers_spawner-8]: started with pid [4032]
Warning [parser.cc:286] parse from urdf file [/usr/share/drcsim-1.0/models/drc_robot/model.sdf].
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
Error [Transport.cc:102] Unable to get topic namespaces in [50] tries.
Error [Node.cc:72] No namespace found
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:57] escalating to SIGKILL on server
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/airobot/.ros/log/412ca1fe-2c9b-11e2-81f2-4c80930ee359/gazebo-2*.log
```

Any help or suggestion, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/198/drc-simulator-can%27t-run-again,-after-installing-gazebo!/) by [Tung Go](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/80/tung-go/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-14**:
Can you post the results of `glxinfo |grep direct` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
```

looks suspiciously like an issue with the GPU driver.  Did the linux kernel get updated and the system requires a reboot?

What does `glxinfo` say?

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tung Go](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/80/tung-go/) on 2012-11-13**:
name of display: :0.0
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  12
Current serial number in output stream:12

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-11-13**:
one possibility is the kernel got updated while you were updating gazebo/drcsim, so the gpu driver is in limbo.  If that's the case, just reboot your computer to rectify this situation.

**Comment by [Tung Go](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/80/tung-go/) on 2012-11-13**:
@hsu: As you and a friend of mine suggested, i did reboot it. But nothing improved! Still the problem occurs now. Another friend of mine also diagnosed and recommended the GPU need an update. Mine is an AMD Radeon. Any further suggesion? Thanks @hsu.

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2012-11-13**:
There are a variety of things that you might need to do to get your GPU working properly.  But none of that is Gazebo-specific and so is out of scope for this forum.  You need to get `glxinfo` succeeding and returning `direct rendering: Yes` in its output before it makes sense to talk about Gazebo.